# Where is server.js in Bitnami?

Tags: bitnami

[bitnami server.js in the course](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrnLr.png)

The teacher has the following directory for server.js in Bitnami. But I don't have this directory and I can't even find documentation for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You teacher is using a really old version of Parse (from 2016). The new Bitnami Parse solution includes the Parse files inside the `/opt/bitnami/parse` directory. You can find the server.js file in there.

If you want to perform any change in the configuration in the solution, we suggest you take a look at our documentation or our community forums in case you have any questions.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/parse/

https://community.bitnami.com/

Comment: Thank you, for your explanation.